# What is the correlation between the pairwise differences of 2 bivariate normal random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, correlation

Given (X,Y) bivariate normal, $U = \frac{X_i - X_j}{\sqrt2\sigma_x}$ and similarly $V = \frac{Y_i - Y_j}{\sqrt2\sigma_y}$ for any two independent pairs $(X_i, Y_i)$ and $(X_j, Y_j)$. Why is this true $\rho(U,V) = \rho(X,Y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct calculation:
$$ \begin{align*} Cov[U, V] 
& = \frac {1} {2\sigma_X\sigma_Y}Cov[X_i-X_j, Y_i - Y_j] \\
& = \frac {1} {2\sigma_X\sigma_Y}\left(Cov[X_i, Y_i] + Cov[X_j, Y_j] + 0 + 0\right) \\
& = \frac {1} {2\sigma_X\sigma_Y}\left(2\rho_{XY}\sigma_X\sigma_Y \right) \\
& = \rho_{XY}\end{align*}$$
Also check that
$$ Var[U] = \frac {1} {2\sigma_X^2} \left(Var[X_i] + Var[X_j]\right)
= \frac {1} {2\sigma_X^2} \left(2\sigma_X^2\right) = 1$$
and similarly for $Var[V] =  1$
Therefore
$$ Corr[U, V] = \frac {Cov[U, V]} {\sqrt{Var[U]Var[V]}} = \rho_{XY}$$

Comment: Thanks so much!
Is it that $Cov(X_i,Y_j) = 0$ because the different indexes indicate identically but independently distributed random variables?

Comment: yes by independence.